# Use only max-height to adjust to content height

Tags: html, css

I have a modal centered horizontally and vertically where body content scrolls when its big.

However when the body content is less than modal height the modal does not resize down to its content.

I tried to use only max-height an not height but then my modal code breaks ...

**Note:** Run the code in full page to see the blank space under body content

```css
.cover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  bottom: 0;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 200;
}

.modal {
  background-color: white;
  margin: 10% auto;
  max-width: 400px;
  height: 60vh;
  max-height: 60vh;
  position: relative !important;
}

.scrollView {
  position: relative;
  border: 2px solid red;
  height: calc(60vh - 100px);
  margin: 50px 0;
  top: 50px;
  overflow: scroll;
  z-index: 800;
}

div.header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 50px;
  max-height: 50px;
  top: 0;
  position: absolute;
  background: lightgreen;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 900;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.header div {
  padding: 0 20px;
}

div.footer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 50px;
  background: orange;
  width: 100%;
}

.body {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi porttitor aliquet orci sit amet fringilla. Duis a ligula consequat, ornare elit eu, tincidunt turpis.
</p>
<p>Nulla faucibus ultrices est eu laoreet. Suspendisse accumsan blandit ipsum ultricies congue. Nam eget leo a elit vestibulum tincidunt in elementum nunc. Nunc cursus lacus eu placerat auctor.
</p>
<div class="cover">
  <div class="modal">
    <div class="header">
      <div>Header</div>
      <div><a href="#">Close</a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="scrollView">
      <div class="body">
        Body short content
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
      Footer
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify your code like below and rely on flexbox inside the modal instead of position:absolute;

```css
.cover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 200;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
}

.modal {
  background-color: white;
  max-width: 400px;
  width:100%;
  max-height: 60vh;
  display:flex; 
  flex-direction:column;
}

.scrollView {
  flex-grow:1;
  border: 2px solid red;
  overflow: auto;
}

div.header,
div.footer{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 50px;
  background: lightgreen;
  padding: 0 20px;
  flex-shrink:0;
}

div.footer {
  background: orange;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi porttitor aliquet orci sit amet fringilla. Duis a ligula consequat, ornare elit eu, tincidunt turpis.
</p>
<p>Nulla faucibus ultrices est eu laoreet. Suspendisse accumsan blandit ipsum ultricies congue. Nam eget leo a elit vestibulum tincidunt in elementum nunc. Nunc cursus lacus eu placerat auctor.
</p>
<div class="cover">
  <div class="modal">
    <div class="header">
      <div>Header</div>
      <div><a href="#">Close</a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="scrollView">
      <div class="body">
        Body <br>short <br>content
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
      Footer
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But your modal window is not centered vertically ... Is it possible to make it center vertically?

Comment: But now the original problem is not solved. You get a lot of white space on body content

Comment: @MiguelMoura check again ;)

Comment: There is still a small problem. Check your latest code with short content: https://jsfiddle.net/mdmoura/odsyju1g/1/ ... Now check it with long scrollable content: https://jsfiddle.net/mdmoura/nztq6cLr/1/. Not the header and footer height get smaller. See? This shouldn't happen. The height of header and footer should be constant.

Comment: @MiguelMoura add `flex-shrink:0;` to header/footer (updated)

Comment: Almost ... Sorry ... I am testing it and trying to find any problem. Check the following example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/modal-flex ... Now decrease de height of the modal. You will see the footer starts to get out of the modal. Any idea why? Everything else seems ok.

Comment: @MiguelMoura you reached the limit and the footer is overflowing (50px + 50px + padding of the content > 60vh) .. add `overflow: auto;` to the modal to notice this

Comment: I see. So I have 50 px (header) + 50 px (footer) + 40px (body padding = 20px + 20px). But how to calculate the correct value so that body collapses perfectly like in your code but Header and Footer never disappears? Do I need to use Calc? I have been trying to solve this but the footer always disappear. Maybe I am missing some calculation. 60vh isn't 60% of viewport height? Thank you

Comment: @MiguelMoura don't add the padding to the body. Conside another container inside where you apply the padding and you will be able to collapse the body past the padding